# I can post text to Twitter in Unity3D but I need to be able to post a photo

Tags: c#, twitter, unity-game-engine

So I got this free plugin from the Unity asset store called Let's Tweet in Unity and it works perfectly for posting text but I cannot figure out how to use  https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.xml

instead of http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml?status={0} which is what it is using now. It is written in C# which I don't really know and I am not experienced in the twitter api either. In general I'm new to coding. I'm learning JS.

This plugin has done what I assume is the hardest part which is talking to twitter with the consumer key, secret, etc. The part that I am guessing needs to be changed is below but I could also send you the whole file.

```
private static readonly string PostTweetURL = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml?status={0}";

    public static IEnumerator PostTweet(string text, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, AccessTokenResponse response, PostTweetCallback callback)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || text.Length > 140)
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("PostTweet - text[{0}] is empty or too long.", text));

            callback(false);
        }
        else
        {
            string url = string.Format(PostTweetURL, UrlEncode(text));
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            parameters.Add("status", text);

            // Need to fill body since Unity doesn't like an empty request body.
            byte[] dummmy = new byte[1];
            dummmy[0] = 0;

            // HTTP header
            Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
            headers["Authorization"] = GetHeaderWithAccessToken("POST", url, consumerKey, consumerSecret, response, parameters);

            WWW web = new WWW(url, dummmy, headers);
            yield return web;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(web.error))
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("PostTweet - failed. {0}", web.error));
                callback(false);
            }
            else
            {
                string error = Regex.Match(web.text, @"<error>([^&]+)</error>").Groups[1].Value;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    Debug.Log(string.Format("PostTweet - failed. {0}", error));
                    callback(false);
                }
                else
                {
                   callback(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Onof. Did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue...

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [UniShare](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/search/unishare), it supports post photo to twitter. Besides, it also supports sharing to lots of other social platforms like Facebook, linked in, etc. And support iOS, Android, Mac.